# List, Convert Str List, replace values, print new str List. Should return ['*', '2', '3', '*', '5']

Tags: python

can any of you help me to identify what am I doing wrong? I know this might be simple but I
am new to programming and Python. I need to return `['*', '2', '3', '*', '5']`. Instead of that I am
getting much more values within the list.

Test to replace values in a List

```
repl_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5]
str_repl_list = str(repl_list)
# print('This is the list to replace: ' + str_repl_list)
# print(type(str_repl_list[0]))

new_str_list = []`enter code here`
print(new_str_list)

for item in str_repl_list:
    replacement = item.replace('1', '*')
    new_str_list.append(replacement)
    for index, char in enumerate(new_str_list):
        print(index, char) # This is to identify what information is being taken as par of the new list
```

Answer (score 3):

when you do a `str(repl_list)`, the outpt is a string `'[1, 2, 3, 1, 5]'`, not a list of strings, so if you iterate  through `str_repl_list` you will get

```
1
,
 
2
,
 
3
,
 
1
,
 
5
]
```

Instead you can avoid that step and convert each item to string inside your for loop  (*str(item)*)

```
repl_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5]
new_str_list = []
for item in repl_list:
  replacement = str(item).replace('1', '*')
  new_str_list.append(replacement)

>>> print(new_str_list)
>>> ['*', '2', '3', '*', '5']
```

you can also use list coprehension

```
>>> print(['*' if x == 1 else str(x) for x in repl_list])
>>> ['*', '2', '3', '*', '5']
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting each item to string, you are converting the entire list into a string. Instead try this list comprehension:

```
str_repl_list = [str(i) for i in str_list]
```

This will go through each item and convert it into a string, then store it in the new list.

Comment: Yes, it's much better to use list comprehension. Maybe at the same time also replace '1' with '*'? It seems that this is also included the question.

Comment: @mcrot This is not about "use a list comprehension instead of a loop", the problem with OP's code is that they convert the list as a whole to string and then iterate the characters in the string instead of elements in the list. Might be clearer if you use the name `str_repl_list`, though, to see where this fits into OP's code.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks - I'm not sure, because the OP asks for "I need to return `['*', '2', '3', '*', '5']`" and `new_str_list = [str(x).replace('1','*') for x in repl_list]` would return him that. I mean, there is no advantage in traversing the list a second time for the replacement, or do I miss sth?

Comment: @mcrot It would not, but it fixes the problem in OP's code. If you use that instead of `str_repl_list = str(repl_list)` the rest of the code will work. You are right that it could all be done in a single list comprehension, though.

Comment: Thanks, okay, now I understand .. he wanted to see what he's doing wrong (as he has written).

Answer (score 1):

since you are appending each element in the list `new_str_list`, to see the desired result you need to print them together, so you need to join them in a string and add all element in the string.

so to see the desired result, you just need to add all elment together

which can be done as

```
str_list_final = ''.join(new_str_list)
```